# Bash script not exiting immediately when `exit` is called

Tags: bash, scripting, exit, terminate

I have the following bash script:

```
tail -F -n0 /private/var/log/system.log | while read line 
do
    if [ ! `echo $line | grep -c 'launchd'` -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'launchd message'
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

For some reason, it is echoing `launchd message`, waiting for a full 5 seconds, and *then* exiting.

Why is this happening and how do I make it exit immediately after it echos `launchd message`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using a pipe, the `while` loop is being run in a subshell. Run it in the main shell instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

while ...
do
   ...
done < <(tail ...)
```

Comment: Invoking bash as sh disables certain features, including process substitution.

Comment: +1, this helped with a four-level pipe which was breaking only when run in a script. Weird stuff.

Comment: This exits absolutely from Putty. Is there any way to exit just from while ?

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by Ignacio, your `tail | while` creates a subshell. The delay is because it's waiting for the next line to be written to the log file before everything closes.

You can add this line immediately before your `exit` command if you'd prefer not using process substitution:

```
kill -SIGPIPE $$
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to control the exit code using this method. It will be 141 which is 128 + 13 (the signal number of `SIGPIPE`).

If you're trying to make the startup of a daemon dependent on another one having started, there's probably a better way to do that.

By the way, if you're really writing a Bash script (which you'd have to be to use `<()` process substitution), you can write your `if` like this: `if [[ $line == *launchd* ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also exit the subshell with a tell-tale exit code and then test the value of "$?" to get the same effect you're looking for:

```
tail -F -n0 /private/var/log/system.log | while read line 
do
    if [ ! `echo $line | grep -c 'launchd'` -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 'launchd message'
        exit 10
    fi
done
if [ $? -eq 10 ]; then exit 0; fi
```